# Connect domain to pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, deployment, dns, pythonanywhere

I did a webpage in pythonanywhere and I'm using the subdomain they gave me (username.pythonanywhere.com) but I have a domain that I want to use for this project (I bought the domain in domain.com). I already expanded my plan in pythonanywhere to put my own domain but I've been trying without sucess. This is the documentation that I've been reading.

[pythonanywhere documentation](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/CustomDomains#configuring-the-domain-at-the-domain-registrar)

[Image of the Domain.com panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwuZV.png)

Is the first time that I make this and a pretty confused.

Comment: Where’s your CNAME record?

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- I took a look at the public aspects of your domain setup (specifically, I used `drill` to look for CNAMEs for `www.floresacosta.com`) and it looks like there's still some stuff you need to set up -- specifically, you need to create a CNAME.  A CNAME is a kind of DNS record; [this is the help page for setting up DNS records on domain.com](https://www1.domain.com/help/article/dns-management-how-to-update-dns-records).  You might also find [our beginner's guide to DNS](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/175/) helpful.